# Bootstrap4: Accessing variables?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I switched from Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4. I am using sass sources which I compile on the run. When I changed the libraries, I started to get error on my media switches, i.e. for

```
@media screen and (min-width: $screen-md-min) {
    padding: 40px 50px;
}
```

I get error 
**Undefined variable: "$screen-md-min".**

What is a correct way to access variables of Bootstrap4?

Thank u.

Answer (score 13):

See [the relevant section of the Bootstrap 4 migration documentation.](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/26a6dc1d16c0efb9783889076e351d15b644ea83/docs/migration.md#responsive-utilities)

The `@screen-*` variables have been replaced by the `$grid-breakpoints` variable along with the `media-breakpoint-up()`, `media-breakpoint-down()`, and `media-breakpoint-only()` helper Sass mixins.

Example usage:

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
    padding: 40px 50px;
}
```

Comment: this works perfectly for BS4 alpha. don't forget other possible breakpoints including  md are: xs, sm, md, lg, and xl (with xl being the added as newest breakpoint) "xl" is really "lg" from previous versions of bootstrap.

Answer (score 5):

With Bootstrap 4 you could use it like this by importing bootstrap/_variables.scss in your .scss file:

```
.your-class-name {
  color: black;

  @media (min-width: map-get($grid-breakpoints, sm)) {
    color: red;
  }

  @media (min-width: map-get($grid-breakpoints, md)) {
    color: blue;
  }

  @media (min-width: map-get($grid-breakpoints, lg)) {
    color: green;
  }

  @media (min-width: map-get($grid-breakpoints, xl)) {
    color: yellow;
  }
}
```

or this:

```
.your-class-name {
  color: black;

  @include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
    color: red;
  }

  @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
    color: blue;
  }

  @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
    color: green;
  }

  @include media-breakpoint-up(xl) {
    color: yellow;
  }
}
```

Fore more details, view [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints) page section responsive breakpoints.

Answer (score 2):

In Bootstrap 4 I could retrieve the screen-md-min value by doing this:

```
$grid-breakpoint-sm: map_get($grid-breakpoints, "sm");
```

Which I found out from looking in bootstrap's _variables.scss file:

```
$print-body-min-width:              map-get($grid-breakpoints, "lg") !default;
```

Answer (score 1):

BS4 replaces Less with Sass. Less use lazy loading for variables whilst Sass does not. So you should declare your variables before using them. Make sure to import `bootstrap/_variables.scss` before your media switches:

```
@import 'bootstrap/variables';
@media screen and (min-width: $screen-md-min) {
    padding: 40px 50px;
}
```

Comment: Not really the case in BS4alpha

Comment: Question is about BS4 – this answer isn't